# Google Maps - second loading is not showing markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a "Google Map code" that is included in each page of a website. On index page everything works fine but when i load other pages the "code" seems to skip the markers setup (the setMarkers function is not executed). Is there a cache issue ?

this is my code

```
function initialize(){
    alert('start');

    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            scrollwheel: false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php print $general_latitude.','.$general_longitude;?>),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);


   setMarkers(map, places);

   alert('start done');
   }



 function setMarkers(map, locations) {
     //alert('set markers');
     var shadow = {
 url: '<?php print get_template_directory_uri().'/css/css-images/shadow.png'; ?>',
 size: new google.maps.Size(59, 59),
 origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
 anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 59)
  };

    var shape = {
   coord: [1, 1, 1, 38, 38, 59, 59 , 1],
   type: 'poly'
   };

   var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    var myOptions = {
                  content: boxText
                  ,disableAutoPan: true
                  ,maxWidth: 700
                  ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-90, -450)
                  ,zIndex: null         
                  ,closeBoxMargin: "-13px 0px 0px 0px"
                  ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                  ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                  ,isHidden: false
                  ,pane: "floatPane"
                  ,enableEventPropagation: false
          };              
    infoBox = new InfoBox(myOptions);         



   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   var beach = locations[i];
   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     shadow: shadow,
     icon: custompin(beach[8]),
     shape: shape,
     title: beach[0],
     zIndex: beach[3],
     image:beach[4],
     price:beach[5],
     type:beach[6],
     type2:beach[7],
     infoWindowIndex : i 
 });

   gmarkers.push(marker);

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     infoBox.setContent('<div class="info_details">'+this.image+' <h2>'+this.title+'</h2> <div class="prop_details">'+this.type+' for '+this.type2+' - '+this.price+'</div>' );
     infoBox.open(map, this);    
     map.setCenter(this.position);      
     map.panBy(380,-190);
  });


  }//end for
  }// end setMarkers
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? do you see the alert?

Comment: Are you including the API code on all the other pages? (you must be including it on the "index" page or you wouldn't see the map, but you don't show it as part of your question)

Comment: APi is included on every page + no errors in console.

Comment: please show `setMarkers()`. What is `places` ?

Comment: added setMarkers() . places is an array with markers info

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle? Are you using a framework (like jquery mobile)? Please provide some info about the structure of the project.